# Cassandra Node Memory Usage Imbalance

Tags: operating-system, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.2 with the new MurMur3Partitioner on centos.

On a 2 node cluster both set up with `num_tokens=256`

I see that one node is using much more memory than the other after inserting a couple million rows with CQL3.

When I run the `free` command
it shows 6GB usage on the second node and 1GB on the seed node.

However, when running

`ps -e -o pid,vsz,comm= | sort -n -k 2`

It shows the java process using about 6.8GB on each node.

Note that I have
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4GB"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="400M"

set in `cassandra-env.sh` on each node.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely related to the general difficulties around reporting accurate memory utilization in Linux, especially as it relates to Java processes.  Since Java processes reserve and allocate memory automatically, what the operating system sees can be misleading.  The best way to understand what a Java process is doing is using JMX to monitor heap utilization.  Tools such as VisualVM and jconsole work well for this.